# Знаки выдаются и за общие вопросы?

Tags: поддержка, знаки

Я тут обнаружил, что получил по знаку за вопрос и ответ, помеченные общими.
Мне казалось, что их только за именные дают, нет?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=178988
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question?userid=178988

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автор общего вопроса/ответа (его создатель) продолжает получать знаки.

[Что представляют собой общие сообщения?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2437/176217)
[How do Community Wiki posts work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/310448)