# Что представляют собой общие сообщения?

Tags: поддержка, faq, общие-сообщения

Некоторые вопросы и ответы отмечены как *общие* и принадлежат [Духу сообщества](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

- Для чего нужны общие сообщения?
- Что происходит с сообщением, которое отмечают общим?
- Как сообщения становятся общими?
- Каким образом можно преобразовать общее сообщение в авторское?

---

Это свободный перевод публикации «[What are Community Wiki posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/)».

Answer (score 8):

### Для чего нужны общие сообщения?

Одна из целей сайта – постоянное непрерывное улучшение качества представленной информации. Сообщения отмеченные как «общие» помогают усилить вики-составляющую сайта.

Более подробно о том, как правильно использовать общие сообщения, см. [«Будущее общих сообщений»](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

### Что происходит с сообщением, которое отмечают общим?

В таких сообщениях авторское право частично переходит от изначального автора всему сообществу. Упрощается процесс редактирования и поддержки актуальности содержимого сообщения и расширяется круг участников, которые могут выполнять действия над сообщением, но без изменения репутации.

Несколько главных особенностей:

- Для того чтобы свободно редактировать общее сообщение, необходима гораздо более скромная репутация (**100** вместо **2000**). <sup>1</sup>
- Голосование по общему сообщению (как «за», так и «против») не влияет на репутацию автора сообщения.
- Принятие общего ответа [не влияет на репутацию автора, давшего этот ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145935/152859).
- Если общий ответ побеждает в конкурсе, награда за него поднимает репутацию согласно общепринятым правилам.
- Автор исходного сообщения отмеченного общим может получить за него знак.
- Автор исходного сообщения сохраняет ту репутацию, которую имел(а) до того, как его/ее сообщение было отмечено общим.
- Автор исходного сообщения продолжает получать уведомления о его изменении или появлении к нему комментариев.
- Участник, указанный как автор, не обязательно является автором исходного сообщения. Вместо этого автором указывается участник с [наивысшим процентом авторства](http://blog.codinghorror.com/mixing-oil-and-water-authorship-in-a-wiki-world/) относительно финальной версии сообщения на основании количества добавленных или удаленных им строк. Если речь идет об авторе исходного сообщения, это количество умножается на 2 (поощрительный фактор).

### Как сообщения становятся общими?

Существует три способа отметить сообщение общим.

- При написании или редактировании **ответа** его автор отмечает его как «общим» (флаг справа под полем для ввода тела ответа). Обратите внимание, что для новых участников это поле недоступно. Также, поле недоступно, если вопрос, к которому публикуется ответ, уже отмечен как общий. <sup>2</sup>
- Модератор может отметить сообщение общим, если предполагает, что сообщение принесет бОльшую пользу сообществу именно в этом виде. Если вы считаете, что ваше сообщение [должно быть отмечено общим](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/), вы можете [отметить его флагом, чтобы привлечь внимание модератора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183).
- Ответ на общий вопрос также будет общим. Ранее вопрос мог быть отмечен общим либо его автором, либо автоматически системой, но [теперь сделать это может только модератор](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism/228940#228940). Когда модератор отмечает вопрос общим, все ответы к нему, как имеющиеся, так и будущие, также будут общими.

### Каким образом можно преобразовать общее сообщение в авторское?

[При необходимости, это могут сделать модераторы.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373)

### Разное

- Сделать сообщение авторским с отката к предыдущей версии сообщения невозможно.
- Последним редактором вопроса может оказаться Дух сообщества<sup>3</sup>, даже если вопрос не имеет статус общего. Так бывает, когда Дух сообщества случайным образом посещает страницы старых вопросов, которые остались без ответа, чтобы привлечь к ним внимание.

<sup>1</sup> Автор исходного сообщения, которое было отмечено общим, может редактировать его *всегда*, даже имея репутацию меньше 100. Другие исправления, сделанные участниками с репутацией менее 100, до вступления в силу должны проходить стандартную процедуру проверки.

<sup>2</sup> Начиная с [октября 2010 года](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67582/152859), при попытке задать вопрос участник не видит флага «общий».

<sup>3</sup> См. [кто такой «Дух сообщества»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0/info), или [учетную запись «Духа»](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

Comment: 1. _"Ранее вопрос мог быть отмечен общим либо его автором, либо автоматически системой"_ - автоматически системой - это в каком случае? 2. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user - а у нас разве перевода нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy: 2 — неожиданно, но в виде вопроса перевода нет. Но есть описание метки, которое я могу рекомендовать на замену этой ссылке: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0/info

Comment: @NickVolynkin Поправил.