# Может ли рядовой участник сделать вопрос общим?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, общие-сообщения

У нас возникла дискуссия на предмет возможности сделать вопрос общим. Может ли не модератор сделать вопрос общим? До текущего момента я был уверен, что да, может. Но, видимо, как показывает практика, этого сделать нельзя. В таком случае, я не понимаю, зачем нужна галочка "общий" под ответом на вопрос:

[image: Общий вопрос и ответ]

Обсуждение было [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706281/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-docker-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5/706282?noredirect=1#comment1052525_706282), теперь комментарии удалены.

Comment: _зачем нужна галочка "общий" под ответом_ - чтобы сделать общим _ответ_

Comment: На данный момент если делать вопрос общим, то все ответы автоматом будут общими и добавлять ответы можно только как общие. Видимо предполагается, что это коллективный вопрос-ответ, как вики и репутация тут не имеет значения. Это может быть нужно в редких случаях. Да и некоторым не очень интересно давать общие ответы, потому что репутация иногда важна и показывает вклад участника в сообщество..А вот общий ответ можно сделать в любой момент потому что..... да по любой из сотен причин. При этом остальные ответы (один или десяток) будут не тронуты  и всем хорошо, все довольны

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что представляют собой общие сообщения?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2436/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Показанная вами галочка делает общим только ответ.

Когда я еще не был модератором и заводил списки литературы, всегда приходилось просить Nofate, чтобы он сделал общим **вопрос**. У меня на нем нужной галочки не было. И теперь при создании вопроса её тоже нет — есть только при редактировании (с учётки модератора).

Когда вопрос становится общим, то вместе с ним становятся общими и ответы. В результате, их авторы лишаются притока репутации и рейтинга по меткам. И снижается порог для редактирования этих ответов. И новые ответы тоже могут быть только общими.

То есть, галочка на вопросе влияет на вклад других участников, а на ответе — только на свой. Наверное, по этой причине галочку на вопросе оставили только модераторам и сотрудникам.

Comment: `есть только при редактировании.` - разве? или этот комментарий относится к редактированию модераторами?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну да, у всех никогда нет, у модераторов нет при создании вопроса и есть при редактировании.